# emberjs ember cli jade templates not compiling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, pug, ember-cli

I am using [ember-cli](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/) to setup my new emberjs application.  While I was able to successfully install jade, it does not appear to be rendering .jade templates added to the /app directory?

Thoughts?  Current package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ember-cli": "0.0.28",
    "originate": "0.1.5",
    "broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler": "^1.5.0",
    "loom-generators-ember-appkit": "^1.1.1",
    "express": "^4.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.2.0",
    "glob": "^3.2.9",
    "broccoli-sass": "^0.1.4",
    "broccoli-csso": "^0.2.0",
    "broccoli-jade": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

There is a rather small template in the `/app` folder named `error.jade` with the following code:

```
doctype html
head
    title
        |Error!
body
    p
        strong
            |Error!
```

When I run `ember serve` or `ember build` it never gets compiled.  Everything else is the standard setup in ember cli.   I ran `npm install --save broccoli-jade` to install it.  Here is an example repo I setup for this issue [embercli-emberjs-test](https://github.com/chrishough/embercli-emberjs-test).  Ideally I would like to compile both handlebars and jade templates.

Thoughts? [github issue](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/752)

Answer (score 0):

try running

> bower install

in your app root.  Some times the post-install routine does not execute automatically.